# List<Future> IndexOutOfBoundsException occurs when try to get returned object from Future

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice, callable

This question is similar to following existing question. I know `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is a `RuntimeException`, therefore it is clear that there is a bug in the code.

[traversing a List<Future> object throws IndexOutOfBounds exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595762/traversing-a-listfuture-object-throws-indexoutofbounds-exception)

In my case this exception actually occurs in the API which actually transfers a file. It gets caught in call() (Lambda) and considered a **failed** for retry.

There are various file transfer tasks in the java project. Therefore I am using `ExecutorService` to satisfy requirements.

There is a list of files from which each file will be supply to `ExecutorService`, where I am passing a **Callable** which eventually return the file object, if it got failed to transfer.

I know I must be doing something wrong.

Please suggest what changes need to be done, I would appreciate your time.

Please do let me know if any additional information require.

(real class and method name replaced with dummy name)

**Exception stack trace**

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at FileTransfer.lambda$transfer$1(FileTransfer.java)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at FileTransfer.transfer(FileTransfer.java)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:476)
    at com.autofixrt.errorhandler.strategy.retry.FileTransfer.lambda$transfer$0(FileTransfer.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Following is the java method which is doing file transfer operation.

**FileTransfer.java**

```
public class FileTransfer {
    public boolean transfer(List<File> fileList) {

            final int size = fileList.size();

            final int[] pos = {0};
            // Also tried with AtomicInteger but gives the same IndexOutOfBoundsException

            final ExecutorService executor = ExecutorUtil.createDefaultExecutor();

            final List<Future<File>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();

            try {

                while (pos[0] < size) {

                    final Future<File> future = executor.submit(() -> {

                        File failed = null;

                        // Exception caused by at below line
                        // Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
                        final File input = fileList.get(pos[0]++); // caused by

                        try {

                            final boolean isSuccess = // API call to transfer file;

                            if (!isSuccess)
                                failed = input;

                        } catch (final Exception e) {

                            failed = input;
                        }
                        return failed;

                    }); // submit ends

                    futureList.add(future);

                } // while ends

                final List<File> failedList = new ArrayList<>(0);

                // iterate over list of futures collected above
                futureList.forEach(f -> {

                    try {

                        // java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
                        final File input = f.get(); // Exception occures at this line

                        if (input != null)
                            failedList.add(input);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Error in retrieving failed from future");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

            } finally {
                ExecutorUtil.shutdown(executor);
                futureList.clear();
            }


            boolean success = true;
            // send failed email, if still failed present
            if (!isEmpty(failed)) {
                success = false;
                // sendErrorEmail(failedList);
            }

            return success;
    }
}
```

**ExecutorUtil.java**

```
public final class ExecutorUtil {

    private ExecutorUtil() { }

    private static final int DEFAULT_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;

    public static ExecutorService createDefaultExecutor() {
        return createExecutor(DEFAULT_THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
    }

    private static ExecutorService createExecutor(int threadPoolSize) {
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
    }

    public static void shutdown(ExecutorService executor) {

        if (isNull(executor))
            return;

        executor.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted

        try {

            // Wait 20 seconds for existing tasks to terminate
            if (!executor.awaitTermination(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {

                executor.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks

                // Wait 10 seconds for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if (!executor.awaitTermination(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS))

                    System.out.println("Pool did not terminate");

                else
                    System.out.println("Thread pool has been shutdown");

            } else
                System.out.println("Thread pool has been shutdown - no await");


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a foreach loop instead of this ugly while(pos[0]) loop?

Comment: this `int[]` as a holder for a mutable `int` is a complete anti-pattern and your bugs are directly related to the poor programming practice and the malformed logic of checking a variable and updating it in a non-atomic fashion to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for your time and comments. I have edited the question to justify how it is different from duplicate. Also in the comments, I have already mentioned that I tried with **AtomicInteger**, which is not solving this error.

Comment: Replacing while loop to foreach did solved the problem initially. Seems early to confirm.

Answer (score -1):

1. Your `int[0]` is not thread safe. Use an `AtomicInteger` instead.
2. Your condition `while (i < size)` is executed on the main thread while the increment `i++` is done on the executor thread. A possible execution is:

   ```
   i = 0;
   while (i < 1) //true
   executor.submit(...)
   //note that i hasn't been incremented yet
   while (i < 1) //true
   i++; //in the first executor thread
   executor.submit(...) //IOOBE
   ```

I wonder why you don't simply write:

```
for (File f : fileList) {
  executor.submit( ... ); //use f directly in the executor
}
```

Comment: `AtomicInteger` will not fix the fact that the read ( if statement ) and the write are not going to be an atomic operation the backwards way this is written.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson agreed, my 1. is more of a side comment - the real problem is addressed in my 2. I believe.

Comment: @assylias I am doing existing code refactor to Java 8 and performance tuning. I was ignorant looking after the existing while loop could cause the problem. Replacing while loop to foreach did solved the problem initially. However it seems too early to confirm that is solved the problem. I will run more tests and confirm.